# Remove 2 vertical and top borders from h:inputText

Tags: css, jsf

I have following JSF component:

```
   <h:inputText value="#{TestComponent.hmspatient.surname}" label="Surname" styleClass="textbox" style="border:none;"/>
```

I want to display only the bottom border (horizontal) and remove all other 3. When I use `border:none` it removes all borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```css
span {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

input {
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<span>Heyyy</span><br>
<input type="text" value="Heyyy" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove each border individually:

```
style="border-top:none; border-left:none; border-right:none;"
```

and that will leave the bottom border in the default style.

or, if you want to specify the bottom border style specifically, you can do:

```
style="border:none; border-bottom:5px solid blue;"
```